# MVC 3 and razor, How to build a structure with _layout within _layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm currently setting up a large project containing 5 different sites. All of these sites have the same "frame" in common (_layout.cshtml in Views/Shared in root).

I've set up a structure where every site is a area and this will work great for our needs. My question is, how can I work with one _Layout.cshtml (a login bar, footer, background) that is the same for all sites and then one _Layout.cshtml for each site that, in turn, is called via a partial view (for example index.cshtml) that, in turn is called via a controller?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, tried to rephrase my question now the best i can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are nested layouts in Razor? There is a tutorial that I used [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/164/Nested-Layout-Pages-with-Razor).

Hope this helps, Matt.